# Software won't update -- error message

Tags: update-manager

I got the usual message that software ready to be updated.  I went to the software updater icon and hit it.   When it comes up and gives me the option to 'install', I hit 'install' as I usually do, but I get an error message.  I don't know what to do with it. I haven't installed anything new recently.  I think I got an update to Firefox the other day and it is working strangely, like youtube videos often won't play and my duckduckgo isn't coming up today, but other sites like Facebook are coming up as usual.

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

```
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-amber-dri: Depends: libglapi-mesa (>= 23.0.4) but 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
```

Comment: My other computer has the same Ubuntu 22.04 on it and I decided to try the update on that one.   It had a LOT of files to update and when done, it said there were more files to update, so I clicked 'install'.  It said they were post update triggers (I think that was it) and installed them.   Then, after the restart it said there was software to download and install, I said ok  and it checked and said my software was up to date.   The other computer had no problem with the update and youtube and duckduckgo both work on that computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by updating using the terminal. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will ask for the password and for confirmation before installing.

I ran afterwards the software updater to install other updates  apt-get didn't find and it run smoothly.

Comment: Perfect.   I used to update with the apt-get when I had NordVPN but haven't for a few months now.  It worked perfectly.   Thanks

Comment: Oops.  Maybe I spoke too soon.   It is crazy but youtube will still not play videos, it just spins.  It did start playing one so I tried another and it is still spinning.  And duckduckgo won't come up.  But the software did update correctly.

Comment: Here's another. . . I thought I'd try uninstalling Firefox and re-installing it.   I went to "Ubuntu Software" and opened it  up.   So far it has been spinning for 2 minutes, looks like it is hung up.   There must be something wrong and i wonder what needs to be done to fix this tangle of software that is causing the mess.

Comment: @PSimdars I think you might have 2 different issues:
1. The problem with the software update tool.
2. The problem with firefox. I have no problems watching videos. Not before the software updater issue, nor after it. And I also updated firefox to the latest version prior to having the software updater issue.